# Amazon Product API with PHP

Tags: php, curl, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I'm trying to integrate Amazon Product API into my website and came across several posts that helped me construct the URL. Only problem is when I execute the code below I get the following error. Am I doing something wrong?

> **Internal Server Error** The server
>   encountered an internal error or
>   misconfiguration and was unable to
>   complete your request. Please contact
>   the server administrator,
>   awsadmin@amazon.com and inform them of
>   the time the error occurred, and
>   anything you might have done that may
>   have caused the error. More
>   information about this error may be
>   available in the server error log.

```
$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "[myaccesskeyhere]";
$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "[mysecretkeyhere]";

$base_url = "http://ecs.amazonaws.com/onca/xml?";
$url_params = array('Operation'=>"ItemSearch",'Service'=>"AWSECommerceService",
 'AWSAccessKeyId'=>$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,'AssociateTag'=>"yourtag-10",
 'Version'=>"2006-09-11",'Availability'=>"Available",'Condition'=>"All",
 'ItemPage'=>"1",'ResponseGroup'=>"Images,ItemAttributes,EditorialReview",
 'Keywords'=>"Amazon");

// Add the Timestamp
$url_params['Timestamp'] = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.\\0\\0\\0\\Z", time());

// Sort the URL parameters
$url_parts = array();
foreach(array_keys($url_params) as $key)
    $url_parts[] = $key."=".$url_params[$key];
sort($url_parts);

// Construct the string to sign
$string_to_sign = "GET\necs.amazonaws.com\n/onca/xml\n".implode("&",$url_parts);
$string_to_sign = str_replace('+','%20',$string_to_sign);
$string_to_sign = str_replace(':','%3A',$string_to_sign);
$string_to_sign = str_replace(';',urlencode(';'),$string_to_sign);

// Sign the request
$signature = hash_hmac("sha256",$string_to_sign,$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,TRUE);

// Base64 encode the signature and make it URL safe
$signature = base64_encode($signature);
$signature = str_replace('+','%2B',$signature);
$signature = str_replace('=','%3D',$signature);

$url_string = implode("&",$url_parts);
$url = $base_url.$url_string."&Signature=".$signature;
print $url;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

$xml_response = curl_exec($ch);
echo $xml_response;
```

**EDIT**

**THE ABOVE CODE NOW WORKS...I WAS MISSING A "?" after the BASE URL**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "[myaccesskeyhere]";
$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "[mysecretkeyhere]";

$base_url = "http://ecs.amazonaws.com/onca/xml?";
$url_params = array('Operation'=>"ItemSearch",'Service'=>"AWSECommerceService",
 'AWSAccessKeyId'=>$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,'AssociateTag'=>"yourtag-10",
 'Version'=>"2006-09-11",'Availability'=>"Available",'Condition'=>"All",
 'ItemPage'=>"1",'ResponseGroup'=>"Images,ItemAttributes,EditorialReview",
 'Keywords'=>"Amazon");

// Add the Timestamp
$url_params['Timestamp'] = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.\\0\\0\\0\\Z", time());

// Sort the URL parameters
$url_parts = array();
foreach(array_keys($url_params) as $key)
    $url_parts[] = $key."=".$url_params[$key];
sort($url_parts);

// Construct the string to sign
$string_to_sign = "GET\necs.amazonaws.com\n/onca/xml\n".implode("&",$url_parts);
$string_to_sign = str_replace('+','%20',$string_to_sign);
$string_to_sign = str_replace(':','%3A',$string_to_sign);
$string_to_sign = str_replace(';',urlencode(';'),$string_to_sign);

// Sign the request
$signature = hash_hmac("sha256",$string_to_sign,$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,TRUE);

// Base64 encode the signature and make it URL safe
$signature = base64_encode($signature);
$signature = str_replace('+','%2B',$signature);
$signature = str_replace('=','%3D',$signature);

$url_string = implode("&",$url_parts);
$url = $base_url.$url_string."&Signature=".$signature;
print $url;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

$xml_response = curl_exec($ch);
echo $xml_response;
```

For anyone that was wondering. You can then navigate the xml_response using simplexml!

Hope this helps someone out there :)

Comment: I'm testing with this, but it says
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.
although my key testing on this url work fine.
http://associates-amazon.s3.amazonaws.com/signed-requests/helper/index.html
Any help please?

Comment: The signature fails in this code because the commas in the `ResponseGroup` section are not URL encoded. Add this line after the other `str_replace`'s and it works fine!

```php
$string_to_sign = str_replace(',', '%2C', $string_to_sign);
```

Comment: @sta4ck0v3rfdl0w

Would you please share with us the reference document to get amazon product search API?

Answer (score -1):

Use Bellow code for the Amazon Product API:

```
<?php
//Enter your IDs
define("Access_Key_ID", "[Your Access Key ID]");
define("Associate_tag", "[Your Associate Tag ID]");

//Set up the operation in the request
function ItemSearch($SearchIndex, $Keywords){

//Set the values for some of the parameters
$Operation = "ItemSearch";
$Version = "2013-08-01";
$ResponseGroup = "ItemAttributes,Offers";
//User interface provides values
//for $SearchIndex and $Keywords

//Define the request
$request=
     "http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml"
   . "?Service=AWSECommerceService"
   . "&AssociateTag=" . Associate_tag
   . "&AWSAccessKeyId=" . Access_Key_ID
   . "&Operation=" . $Operation
   . "&Version=" . $Version
   . "&SearchIndex=" . $SearchIndex
   . "&Keywords=" . $Keywords
   . "&Signature=" . [Request Signature]
   . "&ResponseGroup=" . $ResponseGroup;

//Catch the response in the $response object
$response = file_get_contents($request);
$parsed_xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
printSearchResults($parsed_xml, $SearchIndex);
}
?>
```